# Find an approximation for the number of times you have to find a random variable

Tags: statistics, approximation

> Let $a < b < c$ randomly chosen numbers such that $b > 0$.
>
> Find an approximation for $k$, the number of times it is necessary to choose a random number in the interval $(a, b)$ so the sum of the chosen numbers will be greater than $c$.

I don't even know where to start. I wrote a script in R but I don't know how to formulate it to find a mathematical approximation.

```
tries <- 10^4
i <- 0
thislist <- list(0)
while (i < tries){
 i <- i + 1
 n <- runif(1, a, b)
 k <- 0
 while (n < c){
  k <- k + 1
  n <- n + runif(1, a, b)
 }
 thislist <- append(thislist, k)
 print(i)
}

print(mean(unlist(thislist)))
```

Comment: $k$ is a random variable, so it doesn't make sense to ask what the number $k$ is (or how to approximate $k$). One could ask for the the expectation of $k$, or similar related questions though.

Comment: I am assuming you really wanted to assume $a > 0$, otherwise the number of choices may be infinite -- if you are picking from $(-100,1)$ to get to a sum of $1,000,000$, it will take you a while.

With that assumption, you will need at most $\lceil c/a \rceil$ and at least $\lfloor c/b \rfloor$ choices.

Why don't you try experimenting what happens with simple numbers, e.g. $1,2,20$ or $1.3,20$ and then update your question with what happens? Or with your script, try to fix some $a,b,c$ and get a distribution for $k$

Comment: @MOLD You should clarify what "k = the number of times it is necessary to choose ..." really means. If you're looking at the worst case scenario, then for $ a > 0$ we have $ k = \lceil c/a \rceil $.

Comment: The question asks that I have to find an "average" (I forgot to put it there) approximation for k. So maybe out of all possible scenarios, it should be the expectation as @angryavian said. I tried to experiment with the script but it doesn't help me with the mathematical aspect.

Comment: I later have to compare the k I found using calculations with the one that the script yields.

Comment: The expectation of the sum of the first $n$ choices is $n(b-a)/2$. Comparing this to $c$ can give you a coarse understanding of where the distribution of $k$ is centered (but it won't actually be the expectation of $k$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $a \ge 0$.

The average of each selection is $\frac{a+b}{2}$. If we always get the average, then it will take $\frac{2c}{a+b}$ tries to exceed $c$.

If you modify the choices of $0 \le a < b < c$ below, you will find that the bulk of the distribution of $k$ is near $\frac{2c}{a+b}$, and that the mean of $k$ is also near $\frac{2c}{a+b}$.

```
a <- 0
b <- 2
c <- 20
tries <- 1000

thislist <- numeric(0)
for (i in 1:tries) {
  n <- 0
  k <- 0
  while (n <= c){
    k <- k + 1
    n <- n + runif(1, a, b)
  
  }
  thislist <- c(thislist, k)
}

hist(thislist)
mean(thislist)
2 * c / (a+b)
```

```
> mean(thislist)
[1] 20.679

> 2 * c / (a+b)
[1] 20
```

Comment: This method is accurate for a = 0, but what if we choose a = 17, b = 19, c = 20. As long as the difference is the same they yield the same result. Would there be any way to include a or b into the function?

Comment: I think 2 * c / ( b + a ) works tho

Comment: @MOLD Thanks, corrected my answer